# python prime number query

Tags: python, primes

```
number_to_check=int(input("Enter the number you want to check for prime:"))
a= 2         
while number_to_check != a :
    if number_to_check % a == 0:
        a+=1
        print("Number not prime ")
        break
    if number_to_check % a != 0:
        a+=1
        print("Number prime")
        break
if number_to_check =2:
    print("2 not prime")
```

I can't see a problem or logic error in my code but the code is working incorrectly.

Comment: does your actual code say `if snumber_...` with the `s` in the second if-statement, or is that a typo in posting here?

Comment: Whether the modulo returns 0 or not, you print a result and break the loop.  You'll never check any number larger than 2.  You can't decide that a number is prime until you have checked ALL of the possible factors.

Comment: And 2 is most definitely prime, and you should check that BEFORE going in to the loop.

Comment: For one thing `if number_to_check =2` -> `if number_to_check == 2`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. There are multiple logical problems with the code here. Aside from that, however, please read [ask] and note well that this is **not a discussion forum**. "The code is working incorrectly" is [not an answerable question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236), and generally we don't just look for problems or logic errors which evaded you - it [is your responsibility](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to check the code [carefully and systematically](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) first.

Comment: Questions on Stack Overflow should be about the "why", generally. Try to identify a **specific thing** in the code that has a result different from what you expect; identify **exactly what you do expect**; and then ask about why that result is different. For example, where the code says `if number_to_check % a != 0:`, try to make sure that `number_to_check` always has the value that you expect, that `a` always has the value you expect, and that the result is what you expect. If anything goes wrong, try to find a cause. (For example, what parts of the program can cause `a` to change?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are better ways to do this, but this follows your philosophy:

```
number_to_check=int(input("Enter the number you want to check for prime:"))
if number_to_check == 2:
    print("2 is prime")
else:
    for a in range(2, number_to_check//2):
        if number_to_check % a == 0:
            print("Number not prime ")
            break
    else:
        print("Number prime")
```